# query to display an error if appearing more than 15% of the total traffic in last 1 hour

Tags: splunk

I need to create an alert which will prompt whenever "reason": "LOCKED" appears more than 15% in previous 1 hour. checks to be made every 10m. this should happen only for "operation":"ENROLL" and "operation":"BIND"

i have this query which gives me the locked transactions but if I combine it with operation:BIND or ENROLL then I dont get any results even though the application is throwing logs for these.

index=abc  cf_app_name="stack-overflow"  "reason": "LOCKED" AND "operation":"ENROLL"

below is the sample log

```
{
    "id": "c90f975cb368",
    "source": {
        "domain": "ABC",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "environment": "stage"
    },
    "namespace": "a.b.c",
    "resource": "CARD",
    "operation": "ENROLL",
    "state": "FAILED",
    "tags": ["kpi"],
    "createTime": 156898900,
    "context": {
        "correlationId": "0-6093d36"
    },
    "data": {
        "dpaData": {
            "dpaId": "1d457051052e71730e71cc5a",
            "srctId": "526e1bcf-ca6ce85ee9cb",
            "durbinRights": false
            },
        "dcfData": {},
        "srciData": {
            "srcId": "526e1ca6ce85ee9cb",
            "name": "mcd
           },
        "appInstanceData": {
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\"}",
            "remoteIpAddress": "xx.yy.zz.aa",
            "httpXForwardedFor": "xx.yy.aa.zz"
        },
        "authenticationData": {
            "expiration": false,
            "authenticationResult": {
                "reason": "LOCKED"
            },
            "emailVerified": false,
            "phoneVerified": false
        },
        "consumerData": {},
        "error": {
            "reason": "LOCKED",
            "message": "Access is denied to the requested resource. The user account has been locked.,  card locked time: [166898828]",
            "http-response-code": "400"
        }
    }
}
```

I just need the query which will give the events where "reason": "LOCKED" under the field error appears along with  "operation": "ENROLL"

Answer (score 0):

@DevOps99

I think the sample JSON event is invalid. If your original event the same as you posted then you need to update that also. Please use https://jsonlint.com/ for same.

As per the sample event there is an `operation` field and 2 `reason` fields (`authenticationData.authenticationResult.reason` & `error.reason`). So instead of using `reason` directly try to use above field names.

Like:

```
| where operation="ENROLL" AND 'authenticationData.authenticationResult.reason'="LOCKED"
```

OR

```
| where operation="ENROLL" AND 'error.reason'="LOCKED"
```

Check below sample example.

```
| makeresults
 | eval _raw = "{
    \"id\": \"c90f975cb368\",
    \"source\": {
        \"domain\": \"ABC\",
        \"version\": \"1.0.0\",
        \"environment\": \"stage\"
    },
    \"namespace\": \"a.b.c\",
    \"resource\": \"CARD\",
    \"operation\": \"ENROLL\",
    \"state\": \"FAILED\",
    \"tags\": [\"kpi\"],
    \"createTime\": \"156898900\",
    \"context\": {
        \"correlationId\": \"0-6093d36\"
    },
    \"data\": {
        \"dpaData\": {
            \"dpaId\": \"1d457051052e71730e71cc5a\",
            \"srctId\": \"526e1bcf-ca6ce85ee9cb\",
            \"durbinRights\": \"false\"
        },
        \"dcfData\": {},
        \"srciData\": {
            \"srcId\": \"526e1ca6ce85ee9cb\",
            \"name\": \"mcd\"
        },
        \"appInstanceData\": {
            \"userAgent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36\"
        },
        \"remoteIpAddress\": \"xx.yy.zz.aa\",
        \"httpXForwardedFor\": \"xx.yy.aa.zz\"
    },
    \"authenticationData\": {
        \"expiration\": \"false\",
        \"authenticationResult\": {
            \"reason\": \"LOCKED\"
        },
        \"emailVerified\": \"false\",
        \"phoneVerified\": \"false\"
    },
    \"consumerData\": {},
    \"error\": {
        \"reason\": \"LOCKED\",
        \"message\": \"Access is denied to the requested resource. The user account has been locked.,  card locked time: [166898828]\",
        \"http-response-code\": \"400\"
    }
}" | extract | table id operation "authenticationData.authenticationResult.reason" "error.reason"
| where operation="ENROLL" AND 'authenticationData.authenticationResult.reason'="LOCKED"
```